# VLOOKUP using cell reference with IMPORTRANGE gives error

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, importrange, vlookup

I can't see what I'm doing wrong with this.

**This Doesn't Work**

```
=Vlookup(L2,IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_Le0cMfbHRSgXqhCdzjQrBscFNm6p1sL-DowWdCZ0Fs/edit#gid=1761671943","responses!B2:R8"),4,0)
```

I get this error:

```
Did not find value '102' in VLOOKUP evaluation.
```

[image: Error image]

**This Does Work**

```
=Vlookup(102,IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_Le0cMfbHRSgXqhCdzjQrBscFNm6p1sL-DowWdCZ0Fs/edit#gid=1761671943","responses!B2:R8"),4,0)
```

I get the correct value.

[image: Working image]

The only difference is the first version (not working) uses a cell reference `L2` in the VLOOKUP. The second version (working) uses a static value `102` in the VLOOKUP.

I've tried wrapping in `"` and `'` but neither work.

Can someone please help me fix this so it works with a cell name and explains why my solution isn't working?

[image]

Comment: @pnuts, thanks for catching that. I corrected the typo between the 4 and 5.

Comment: @pnuts, sorry about the poorly worded question. I'm running on fumes... I've updated the question in an attempt to clarify. Basically I receive an error when using "cell reference" and I get the correct value when I use a static number for the reference.

Comment: I just tested it. the cell L2 has "text" 102 in it and the vLookup cell has the "number" 102 in it. This populates "L2" `=arrayformula(SUBSTITUTE(K2:K,"#",""))` so I guess I need to figure out how to make this return a number instead of text?

Comment: That worked! It converted it to a number. Will that always convert to number or only when paired with SUBSTITUTE?

Comment: Hey Mr. B, If I have answered your question to your satisfaction please select my response as the answer to your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

VLOOKUP is format sensitive. It neither 'matches' text to number nor number to text, even where on screen the *appearance* is identical. This is a standard [gotcha](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gotcha), though unfortunately not mentioned [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318). (Another is 'trailing spaces', specially NBSP, which can complicate diagnosis.)

However the data (whether the `search_key` or part of the `range`) need not be reformatted for VLOOKUP to work as the 'conversion' may be done 'on the fly'.

For example, converting a text `search_key` to numeric format can be achieved by prepending `--` (the [double unary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_operation)), or by coercion with `1*` (multipying by `1`) within a formula.

In OP's case this might mean replacing `L2` with `--L2` or `1*L2`.

Answer (score 1):

B,

A better way to resolve your problem might be to wrap the formula you are putting into M2 in an `IFERROR()` formula. & have the first parameter coerced as text by appending an empty space character to it i.e. `L2&""` & the second parameter coerced as a number i.e. `L2*1` that why it won't matter how the user inputs the information it will still evaluate the `VLookUp()` properly.

**So your formula** `=Vlookup(L2,IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_Le0cMfbHRSgXqhCdzjQrBscFNm6p1sL-DowWdCZ0Fs/edit#gid=1761671943","responses!B2:R8"),4,0)`

**Would now instead be:** `IFERROR(Vlookup(L2&"",IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_Le0cMfbHRSgXqhCdzjQrBscFNm6p1sL-DowWdCZ0Fs/edit#gid=1761671943","responses!B2:R8"),4,0),Vlookup(L2*1,IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_Le0cMfbHRSgXqhCdzjQrBscFNm6p1sL-DowWdCZ0Fs/edit#gid=1761671943","responses!B2:R8"),4,0))`

**Using Arrays you won't have to copy and paste your formula each time a new user fills out your form**
So if you change your `VLookUp()` *search_key* from `L2` to `L2:L` and wrap your entire `VLookUp()` in an `ARRAYFORMULA()` it will allow the formula to propogate downward as needed.

This would make your formula `=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(Vlookup(L2:L&"",IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_Le0cMfbHRSgXqhCdzjQrBscFNm6p1sL-DowWdCZ0Fs/edit#gid=1761671943","responses!B2:R8"),4,0)),ARRAYFORMULA(Vlookup(L2:L*1,IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_Le0cMfbHRSgXqhCdzjQrBscFNm6p1sL-DowWdCZ0Fs/edit#gid=1761671943","responses!B2:R8"),4,0)))`

Good Luck
-Xzila

Answer (score 0):

your **L2** cell is formatted (evaluated) as "text" which results in **`#N/A`**

to resolve it you have 2 options:

- select cell **L2** and go to **Format > Number > Number**

  > [image: 1]
- wrap cell **L2** into **`VALUE()`** which will convert it into numeric value eg. use this formula:

  ```
  =VLOOKUP(VALUE(L2),
   IMPORTRANGE("1_Le0cMfbHRSgXqhCdzjQrBscFNm6p1sL-DowWdCZ0Fs",
               "responses!B2:R8"), 4, 0)
  ```

  > [image: 5]